# Python Chapter divider

Tags: python

I am struggling for a lot of hours now to create a script that will parse my text.

I have a text that looks like the one below. And what I am trying to do is go through a chapter, look at all the articles inside it, then output a dictionary, that has the chapter's name as key and as values for each article there's a list that contains all the articles referred to that one.

Below is sample example of the text

> **CHAPTER I**
>
> **Art. 1** - **(1)** All the vehicles that enter the public road are under the >regulations of the Emergency Ordinance as stated in **art. 2, par. (2)** and >excluded from this are the vehicles listed in **art.7, par. (6)**.
>
> **Art. 2** - **(1)** TEXT TEXT TEXT **art. 3** TEXT TEXT
>
> **(2)** Text text text
>
> **Art. 3** - **(1)** Text referring to **art. 1** text text
>
> **Art. 4** - Text not referring to other articles
>
> **CHAPTER II**

Example output:

**CHAPTER1** = {**art.1** : ["art.2;par.2","art.7;par.(6)"]; **art.2** : ["art. 3"]; **art. 3** : ["art. 1"]; **art.4** : "No reference"}

And this script should store this CHAPTER so I can parse it and output something based on the parsing results.

codul_rutier.txt is the file I have to go through

```
cod_rutier= open('codul_rutier.txt','r')
text = cod_rutier.read()

for chapter in text:
    chapter.split('CHAPTER')
    for line in capitol:
            if re.match(r'^Art.', line):
                    print line
                    break
```

I don't even know how to start doing that, I have tried lots of ways of opening the file to read chapter by chapter, splitting, for loops inside if loops.

If anybody can help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: why start a new question when the other was put in hold yesterday?

Comment: Probably the better way (instead of asking this new question) would be to add your code to [your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53653563/9225671); it was put on hold because it needs more information, like your code for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may start with the following code. It contains 3 regular expressions `chapter_re`, `art_re`, and `link_re`. `borders` and `new_borders` are used to keep positions of matches to search between matches later. `chapter_zero` is a name for the text before `CHAPTER I`. I am not experienced with regular expressions so I guess the code may be significantly improved. I learned about regular expressions from `Programming in Python 3: A Complete Introduction` by Mark Summerfield and try expressions online on the website https://regex101.com/.

```
import re

chapter_re = re.compile('(?P<chapter>CHAPTER [IVX]+)')
art_re = re.compile('(?P<art>^Art. [0123456789]+) - ', re.MULTILINE)
link_re = re.compile('(?P<link>[Aa]rt[.][ ]*[0123456789]+[,]*[ ]*[Pp]ar[.][ ]*[(]*[0123456789]+[)]*|[Aa]rt[.][ ]*[0123456789]+)', re.MULTILINE)

with open('1.txt', mode='r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    data = file.read()

chapters = ['chapter_zero']
borders = [[0, None]]
result = {'chapter_zero': dict()}

# search for CHAPTERs
for match in chapter_re.finditer(data):
    result[match.group('chapter')] = dict()
    chapters.append(match.group('chapter'))
    borders[-1][1] = match.span()[0]
    borders.append([match.span()[1], None])

borders[-1][1] = len(data)

for chp, brd in zip(chapters, borders):

    arts = ['art_zero']
    new_borders = [[0, None]]

    # search for Arts
    for match in art_re.finditer(data[brd[0]:brd[1]]):
        result[chp][match.group('art')] = list()
        arts.append(match.group('art'))
        new_borders[-1][1] = match.span()[0]
        new_borders.append([match.span()[1], None])

    new_borders[-1][1] = brd[1] - brd[0]

    # search for links
    for art, nbrd in zip(arts, new_borders):
        for nmatch in link_re.finditer(data[brd[0]:brd[1]][nbrd[0]:nbrd[1]]):
            result[chp][art].append(nmatch.group('link'))

# printing results        
for k, v in result.items():
    print(k)
    for k, v in v.items():
        print('\t{}: {}'.format(k, v))
    print()
```

Output:

```
chapter_zero

CHAPTER I
    Art. 1: ['art. 2, par. (2)', 'art.7, par. (6)']
    Art. 2: ['art. 3']
    Art. 3: ['art. 1']
    Art. 4: []

CHAPTER II
```